# Is there a software that stitch 4 images together to form 1 big image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose I have a phone with bad camera, I want a good quality image. I take a photo at each corner of a document. So I will have 4 photos. I want to concatenate these photos together to get one big photo that shows the entire document. This requires sophisticating computer vision techniques to combine 4 images that are taken at slightly different angle. The algorithm needs to find out the overlapped part between photos and merge them together.

I'm wondering if there's an app on a phone that does this. Or at least a topic that I search more about. Please suggest me either an app or topic name.

Comment: For what OS should this be? How much money you'd be willing to spend? There's plenty of "panorama stitching" software around for different OSes (though I'm not 100% sure panorama stitching would always work with multiple rows, as you'd need it). [Hugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugin_(software)) might be worth a try. Some more potential candidates [are listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_stitching_software).

Comment: Windows and Android

Comment: Hugin should work on Windows. Do you mean the software must run on both, Windows AND Android – or at least on one of them? And what about the price?

Comment: Hugin works well; on Windows and Linux, and Microsoft still has Image Composite Editor (ICE) for Windows, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52459 Both are free.

Comment: I don't mind about the price. It must work on either Windows or Android. It's best to work on Android as I would like to take photo of documents, stitch them and then send to people. If it works on PC then I would need to copy the photos to the PC first which can be cumbersome.